# Legendre Polynomials Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am trying to calculate the 720th Legendre polynomial with scipy:

```
>>>from scipy.special import legendre 
>>>print(legendre(720))
```

it prints the powers correctly but returns NAN for the coefficients how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a [`float` overflow error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). If you use the `monic` keyword of the `legendre` function you get non-`nan` coefficients:

```
>>> from scipy.special import legendre  
>>> print(legendre(720, monic=True))
```

720 sounds like a high number, maybe it's more stable to use the `eval_legendre` function.